# Having trouble with SQL Interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I need to get the sum of data from a particular date going back one year. But I am having difficult with the Interval

```
Select 0 - sum(l.icdetailquantity )
    from inventoryline l 
    where l.icmasterid = 'WAD185967E' and l.icdetailtranstype = 5 
        and l.icdetaildate <= '01-Jan-2019' and l.icdetaildate >  Now() - interval '1 year'
```

This works as expected but I need to passs a date not use Now()

```
Select 0 - sum(l.icdetailquantity )
    from inventoryline l 
    where l.icmasterid = 'WAD185967E' and l.icdetailtranstype = 5 
        and l.icdetaildate <= '01-Jan-2019' and l.icdetaildate >  '01-Jan-2019' - interval '1 year'
```

the second SQl give an error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "01-Jan-2019"
LINE 4: ...detaildate <= '01-Jan-2019' and l.icdetaildate >  '01-Jan-20...
```

Comment: You can just cast the string to date like the following: `'01-Jan-2019'::date - '1 year'::INTERVAL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to subtract a year from a string. This does not work, you have to first cast youru string to a date object using:

```
to_date(date_string,format)
```

Example that will work for you:

```
to_date('01-Jan-2019', 'DD-Mon-YYYY') - interval '1 year'
```

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-to_date/

Comment: Your date pattern does not fit to your date string. Consider the - characters ;)

Comment: Thanks @S-Man - I missed that one!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with

```
Select 0 - sum(l.icdetailquantity )
from inventoryline l 
where l.icmasterid = 'WAD185967E' 
  and l.icdetailtranstype = 5 
  and l.icdetaildate <= date '2019-01-01' 
  and l.icdetaildate >  date '2019-01-01' - interval '1 year'
```

From the documentation I'm looking at (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) the "date" keyword seems to be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the intervention, I have edited my answer !